# Why can you use the same name in struct definitions?

Tags: c, struct

I recently found this code:

```
struct foo  { int foo; } foo;
```

And I compiled this snippet (with an empty `main()` function of course!), and it compiled without a warning. Why is this legal?

Comment: why not? A field is not a struct, so what's wrong with `foo.foo`?

Comment: A struct name (tag), a struct member, and a variable all exist in separate name spaces, so it's legal to use the same name in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can tell them apart by the context in which they appear. C 2018 6.2.3, “Name spaces of identifiers,” says:

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate *name spaces* for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> — *label names* (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the *tags* of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any of the
> keywords `struct`, `union`, or `enum`);
>
> — the *members* of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the `.` or
> `->` operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called *ordinary identifiers* (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Answer (score 0):

Names in C used to be in namespaces.
In your example, the name foo appears in the struct, struct field, and global namespaces.
This duplicate situation was allowed probably because it takes extra computation to find collisions between those namespaces, and computation used to be very expensive.
Ever since, C maintains backwards compatibility because that’s what C does.

Comment: Re “Names in C used to be in namespaces”: The name spaces have not changed in standard C; they were the same in 1989 C as they are now.

Comment: Re “struct, struct field, and global namespaces”: The standard calls these tags, members, and ordinary identifiers.

Comment: Re “This duplicate situation was allowed probably because it takes extra computation to find collisions between those namespaces, and computation used to be very expensive”: That describes allowing duplicates as burden undertaken to reduce computation. It is not; supporting separate name spaces is a feature to allow programmers more latitude in naming. This is especially so in the separate name spaces for separate aggregates; some pre-standard C implementations had only one space for members, so you could not use `struct foo { int a, b, c; }; struct bar { double a, b, c; };`.